# How to generate number 1 and 0 with mixing ratio 0.5 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

The `Uniform Crossover` uses a fixed `mixing ratio` between two parents. 
Unlike `one- and two-point crossover`, the `Uniform Crossover` enables the parent chromosomes to contribute the gene level rather than the segment level.
If the mixing ratio is `0.5`, the offspring has approximately half of the genes from first parent and the other half from second parent.So i need to generate mask like

**mask1:** 0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
**mask2:** 1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1

Here the **mixing ratio 0.5**. So i need to generate 0 and 1 with this mixing ratio of `0.5`.
**I tried like this in matlab:**

```
 mask1=round(rand(1,IndLength));//IndLength=10 suppose
 mask2=not(mask1);
```

and It didn't give 0 and 1 with mixing ratio of 0.5 all the time.Is there any way to generate such random number with mixing ration of `0.5` in `matlab`??

Comment: Your example has 11 elements. From the comment I assume it should be 10?

Comment: It can be any number of elements.Actually IndLength can be 10,11,100etc.But the mixing ratio of 1 and 0 will be close or equal to 0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randomly permute the numbers between 1 and IndLength, then take every number above IndLength/2 as a 1

```
randperm(IndLength)>IndLength/2
```

For odd numbers, this solution will always have one additional 0

Comment: I like this approach. :] Mine would have been a little bit more complicated, like ```A = [ zeros(1, IndLength/2) ones(1, IndLength/2) ]; A = A( randperm(length(A)) );```

Comment: @MatthiasW. That was also my initial approach, but I dropped it be cause it breaks for odd numbers. You can fix it, but then it was simply to complicated.